# Python process data statistics runs very slow while using tuple in dictionary

Tags: python, list

I wrote a python script to calculate the min, max, avg values of items in a file.
However the program runs slower and slower after few hundred k lines. I can make perl do the same thing very fast but I want to learn the right way in Python. Is there anyway to  speed up it?

```
import sys
import re


filename = sys.argv[1]
resultFile = open(filename, 'r')

netTbl = {}
count = 0;
# Target file line example: "itemA: 0.110"
matchLine = re.compile( r"(.*):\s+([0-9\.]+)" )
for line in resultFile:
    result = matchLine.match(line);
    if( result ) :
        count +=1 
        if( count%10000 == 0 ): print str(count) + ":" + str(len(netTbl))

        name =  result.group(1)
        value = result.group(2)

        if( netTbl.has_key(name) ):
            ( minVal, maxVal, avgVal, numOfInsts ) = netTbl[name]

            if( maxVal < value ): maxVal = value
            if( minVal > value ): minVal = value

            avgVal += value
            numOfInsts += 1
            netTbl[name] = ( minVal, maxVal, avgVal, numOfInsts)
        else:
            netTbl[name] = (value, value, value, 1)
```

The input file is like

```
itemA: 0.1
itemA: 2.1
itemA: 0.4
itemA: 0.2
.....
..... (repeat itemA for million lines)
itemB: 2.9
itemB: 3.8
itemB: 5.76
itemB: 6.3
..... (repeat itemB for million lines)
```

I have got the answer. I forget to cast value to float. So the string is getting larger and larger. To correct the code

```
#value = result.group(2)
value = float(result.group(2))
```

Comment: It won't change the speed, but if you follow [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) your code will look better. Also, why create a new immutable tuple each time you need to change? If you use e.g. a list or dictionary you can change it in-place, which may speed things up a bit.

Comment: I also tried list in dictionary but the speed is the same. If I only put one value in the dictionary it is very fast. Maybe I should try putting just a index in the dictionary and point it to an array.

Comment: _"If I only put one value in the dictionary it is very fast."_ At first sight, I wonder if this isn't caused by the call of `__hash__` on tuples. To be confirmed though... Maybe you should [profile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code to clearly identify the bottleneck.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that suggests it shouldn't run in `O(N)` time (where `N` is the total number of lines in the input file). How large is the `netTbl` dictionary getting? Dictionary operations are generally `O(1)`, but might get much worse if the hash table grows bigger than available memory (so parts of it get swapped out). Your example data suggests it should remain fairly small, but your diagnostic `print` call suggests the opposite.

Comment: I got the answer. I didn't cast "value" to float. So it keeps getting longer and longer. I think it's the string copy/cast slows it down. Thank you guys for thinking with me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for statistical calculation, here is working example:

```
import pandas as pn
file_name = './exmp.txt'
names = ['class', 'value']
df = pn.read_csv(file_name, sep=': ', names=names, engine='python')
print 'Max values'
print df.groupby('class').max()
print 'Min values'
print df.groupby('class').min() 
print 'Avr values'
print df.groupby('class').mean()
```

and the produced output is:

```
Max values
       value
class       
itemA    2.1
itemB    6.3
Min values
       value
class       
itemA    0.1
itemB    2.9
Avr values
       value
class       
itemA   0.70
itemB   4.69
```

Pandas use simple SQL-like group by syntax, so its easy to use and fast to calculate

Comment: Wow, this is exact what I need. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. How fast it's running on your file? (I've tested it on like 20 rows)